# Finding the numerical approximation for the derivative $F ′ ( x )$ without the actual function

Tags: calculus, summation, taylor-expansion, approximation

I need to find a numerical approximation for the derivative $F'(x)$ of an appropriately smooth function $F(x)$ at $x=0$. However I do not know the actual function $F$. I have this formula:

$$F'(0) \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n} F(x_i)w_i$$

Where I have the values of $x_i$ and $w_i$, $i=1....n$. However I do not have the actual function $F$ so am unsure how to evaluate it? I know there is a similar thing for integration (Gaussian Quadrature) but I was wondering if anyone has anything for this problem!

Comment: What do you have? A few numerical points of the function? You could approximate F(x) by interpolating the points (with linear, cubic splines or a general model fit) using the points you do have and then running this equation on the interpolation? 

If you don't have any points It sounds like there is no information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea

Let's assume a line $F(x) = a x + b$ for some unknown $a$ and $b$ this implies
$$
a \approx w_1 F(x_1) + w_2 F(x_2) + \cdots
$$
$$
a \approx w_1 (a x_1 + b) + w_2(a x_2 + b) + w_3 (a x_3+b) + w_4(a x_4+b)
$$
$$
a(1-w_1 x_1 - w_2x_2 - w_3 x_3 - w_4 x_4)  \approx b(w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4)
$$
$$
a  \approx \frac{b(w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4)}{(1-w_1 x_1 - w_2x_2 - w_3 x_3 - w_4 x_4)}
$$
or even
$$
\frac{a}{b}  \approx \frac{(w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4)}{(1-w_1 x_1 - w_2x_2 - w_3 x_3 - w_4 x_4)}
$$
that way you have all the terms on the right, does that sound along the right lines? There should be another equation to try and solve for $b$ as well as that is currently unknown.. Might be able to get something out of the Taylor expansions by subtracting different terms similar to the [Verlet integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration)?
$$
\vec{v}(t)
=
\frac{\vec{x}(t + \Delta t) - \vec{x}(t - \Delta t)}{2\Delta t}
+ \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^2).
$$